# How Can I Select needed information in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My BD:

[image: Angajat]

[image: Departament]

I need to select the column with departament.nume which have <=3 records in tabel angajat.departament_id.

i tried:

```
SELECT departament.nume
FROM (angajat INNER JOIN
      departament
      ON angajat.departament_id=departament.id_dep
     )
where count(angajat.id_dep)<=3;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: You need GROUP BY, and HAVING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT d.nume
FROM departament d LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a.departament_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM angajat a
      GROUP BY a.departament_id
     ) a
     ON a.departament_id = d.id_dep
WHERE COALESCE(cnt, 0) < 3 ;
```

Note the use of `LEFT JOIN` to be sure that departments with no rows in `agnajat` are included in the result set.

Comment: Needlessly complicated, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT departament.nume 
FROM angajat 
INNER JOIN departament
    ON angajat.departament_id=departament.id_dep
GROUP BY departament.nume
HAVING COUNT(*)<=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group By` and `Having`

```
SELECT d.nume,
FROM angajat a JOIN departament d ON a.departament_id = d.id_dep
GROUP BY d.nume
HAVING COUNT (d.nume) <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a subquery.

```
SELECT departament.nume 
FROM departament
LEFT JOIN angajat ON angajat.departament_id=departament.id_dep
GROUP BY departament.id_dep
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
```

If you don't want departments with *no* angajat records, use an inner join instead.

If you want the counting to include together departments with the same nume but different id_dep, group on nume instead.

If you don't want that, but only want each nume returned only once, select DISTINCT departament.nume.